# Close modal dialog (form window) after saving via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, list, sharepoint

I have a form that opens in DispMode via such a link: `https://mysite/tools/EmployeeList/SitePages/StartEL.aspx?&launch=128&launchlist=Zutrittsberechtigung&launchmode=disp`

[image: Form]

The problem is that when I click on "Interflex" (Save) the form saves and reopens the page with the window. This is because the Interflex button has the following JavaScript line:

```
NWF$("button, .stdsubmit").click();
```

I want the form to close after saving, but I have no idea how to achieve that. Worked about 6 hours on that without finding a solution, but I think it's very simple (without me having found it yet). I tried `window.close();` and `window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose();` and 
`SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, 1);` without success.

Can someone tell me how the form can close automatically after saving (without it refreshing the whole page because that would open it again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use NINTEX FORMS, you can use the code below to close the dialog.

```
NWF$(this).dialog('close');
```

Refer to: [DEVELOPING COMPLEX AND DYNAMIC FORMS SOLUTION EASILY IN SHAREPOINT USING NINTEX FORMS](http://www.ashu-tosh.com/2017/01/developing-complex-and-dynamic-forms.html)

If it still not works, try to use the code below.

```
window.location.href=window.location.href;
```

or

```
parent.location.href=parent.location.href;
```